# More efficient way to add multiple records

Tags: google-app-maker

So this works but it takes 15 seconds for a spreadsheet with 60 items.

```
function addToModel(name,birth,age){

  var newRecord = app.models.ImportData.newRecord();
  newRecord['PRESIDENT'] = name; 
  newRecord['BIRTH_PLACE'] = birth; 
  newRecord['AGE_ELECTED'] = age; 
  app.saveRecords([newRecord]);


}


function getSpreadsheet(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("zzz");
var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

 THIS WAS WAY ONE, TAKES 15 SECONDS  

for (var i=1; i<data.length;i++)
    {
     addToModel(data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3].toString());
    }//for loop


}
```

but I noticed that the command is saveRecordS not saveRecord and with anything in google apps script, the fewer calls the better, so I tried this but it doesn't work

```
//SAME SPREADSHEET INFO
var result = [];

for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
    var newRecord = app.models.ImportData.newRecord();
    newRecord['PRESIDENT'] = data[i][1]; 
    newRecord['BIRTH_PLACE'] = data[i][2]; 
    newRecord['AGE_ELECTED'] = data[i][3].toString(); 
    result.push(newRecord);
    }//for loop  

app.saveRecords([result]);
```

Expected result: new records in my table, much faster than the first version. Actual result: "Cannot read property "key" from undefined" which is triggered from the last line (saveRecords). I tried both app.saveRecords(result) and ([result]), same problem both times.

Note: this example is from an appmaker university tutorial that no longer works because of the changes for appmaker v2.

Comment: Since your result is an array of records in your second script, the proper call should be `app.saveRecords(result)`. Although I am not sure why it gives you a key error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's model.newRecord() takes time for each new item created, while time on app.saveRecords() is ignorable.
Could you please confirm that you are EU user? as we EU user are facing same issue ([link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129738211)) due to the server location, if it is the case, please help star that issue and give more info to help Google solve that issue. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, not an EU user. But I'm chunking my inputs so i'm down to under 2 minutes to replace 3000 records so I'm happy enough.